# R: how to apply a complicated function to each column in a dataframe, to out put new dataframe for each column?

Tags: r

I've read a few posted but none of them solves my problems so far. Here's what I am trying to do:

My input data: 
I have this dataframe with all the rows are products, all the columns are the standards which the product are reviewed against.The goal is to look at the pass/fail rate of each standard, and see which one got passed the most, and which standard is the one all products found hard to met.

(seems like I can't copy paste a table here, so I type below what the data frame looks like)

```
**Source** **sample_ID** **Standard_a** **Standard_amn** **Standard_df**
Product1       1              Yes                Yes               NA
Product1       2              Yes                NO                Yes
...            ...            Yes                Yes               NA
Product1       10             Yes                Yes               NO
Product2       1              Yes                NO                YES
...            ...            ..                ....               ...
Product2       8              Yes                Yes               Yes
Product3       1              Yes                NA                NA
....                          Yes                Yes               YES
```

- there are some rules about sampling the products, and valid entries for column entry (Yes means pass the standard, no means no, NA means not available etc). I've created a function to take care of it.
- But my struggle is how to apply my function to all the columns.

**Here is my function for one column (the 14th column), which I try to make it a loop or something to be used automatically on all columns**

```
#take product info columns 1:3 and the 14th standard column: named um9d_f6, 
and create a clean dataframe of this column, I call it x

    x <- appeals_clean %>%
#select column um9d_f6, I use it's position here, which is 14
      select(1:3,14) %>% 
      #group by source (which is product)
      group_by(source) %>%
      #code NA and missing as 0: this are the specific coding rule for pass and fail
      mutate(convert_num = ifelse(um9d_f6 %in% c('YES','NO','AC'),1,0),
             cum_elig = cumsum(convert_num),
             max_cum_elig = max(cum_elig)) %>%
      #get rid of: 1.empty entries after max eligible is reached 2.not enough eligible files 3.after eligible files reach 10
      filter(!((max_cum_elig == cum_elig & um9d_f6 == '')|max_cum_elig <8|(max_cum_elig>10 & cum_elig >10)))


    # now with the clean data from column 14 (again, named um9d_f6, now I calculate the pass rate)
    y <- x %>%
      group_by(source) %>%
      summarise(um9d_f6_n_Pass = sum(um9d_f6 %in% c('YES','AC')),
                um9d_f6_Rate = n_Pass/10)
```

The Y output dataframe looks like this,

```
**Source**  **um9d_f6_n_Pass** **um9d_f6_Rate**
Product1       10         100  
Product2      8             80
Product3      8            80
Product2       8          80
Product3       10           100
```

My struggle is how can I use a loop or other functions to get this y summary dataframe for each of the standard columns in the dataframe. So that I don't need to manually adjust for the column position and it's column name each time I use this function I created (there are about 60 standards, so hopefully I don't needs to do this manually)...

I've tried loops but haven't figured out 
1. how to refer to the column in the function for x and 
2. how to name the new columns in Y according to the input column name.
**eventually I will left join all those new output dataframe Y that's why I need the naming to reflect it's source column names.**

Any suggestions/recommendation would be greatly appreciated!

thank you

Leo

Comment: Can you please share your dataset in a copy paste friendly format?

Comment: This seems like a situation where you could gather the data into long format, apply the formula, and then spread wide again. Is the formula the same for all applicable columns?

Comment: thanks Jon! convert the data wide to long then loop through unique values works!